# Android: Having force close when accessing the media store

Tags: android, image, android-intent, photo, mediastore

I seems to receive a force close when turning off the phone and turning back on and when I on to the application which require to load the photos with media store , it force close. It has no problem when I wait for awhile before going to the application. Do I need to check anything before using the media store.

The error below may or may not related I don't actually sure.

**Log**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position 0
at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:242)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472)
at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1030)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5112)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5112)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5112)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5112)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5112)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2411)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2003)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1242)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1417)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1135)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4652)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: need to see your code can you paste the code?

Comment: post your code first here..

Comment: The reason why it failed to "move cursor to position 0" should be that the `Cursor` is empty. A `CursorAdapter` when used correctly should not try to do that. The problem should therefore lie within the code that loads the cursor or the code directly related to the CursorAdapter. Especially the `CursorAdapter` constructor you use is of interest. If it auto-requeries it could potentially cause that problem.

Comment: I can't show the code coz I don't know which part of the code cause it. I may have a look at that... Thanks.. how do i set auto-requeries to disable?